# Selecting Last names with regex in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a vector that I need to extract the last name into a list. I will then use the list to compare against a set of last names using match. I am having issues doing extracting the last name. Here is an example of

```
Suzanne Sar Abay bob, Lucy Heaton, Lynn Slaney, Michael Hughes,
```

I need to the last names of these.

```
vector <- gsub("\s(\w+)$", "", data_agent$Name, perl = TRUE)
```

This ends up giving me the Suzanne Sar Abay, Lucy, Lynn, Michael. Not the last names. Regex selects the last name successfully. However, realized `gsub` replaces the value.

```
vector1 <- gsub("(.+)\s\w+$", "", data_agent$List.Name, perl = TRUE)
```

This is suppose to select everything except the last name but it is not working. All it returns is blanks. "" "" ""

I was wondering if someone can help me with this?

Comment: What happens if they have, say "Junior" or "III" at the end of their name?  If `Michael Hughes` was `Michael Hughes III`, would you want `Hughes III` or just `Hughes`?

Comment: @akrun I didn't touch the code itself, just the indentation. But it seems that using Ctrl + K changed `\s` and `\w` for `\\s` and `\\w`.

Comment: @Pascal Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @RichardScriven I hadn't really thought about that. I think for the purposes of the problem we can assume there are additions to the last name. If there are it is negligible in the data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple. Just remove all the characters upto the last space.

Simply use sub,

```
sub(".*\\s", "", data_agent$Name)
```

`.*` is greedy by default which matches all the characters upto the last and then it backtracks to last space because we included `\\s` next to `.*`. So it matches all the chars upto the last space.

**Example:**

```
> x <- c('Suzanne Sar Abay bob', 'Lucy Heaton', 'Lynn Slaney', 'Michael Hughes')
> sub(".*\\s", "", x)
[1] "bob"    "Heaton" "Slaney" "Hughes"
```

**OR**

Just extract the last word.

```
> library(stringr)
> str_extract(x, "\\w+$")
[1] "bob"    "Heaton" "Slaney" "Hughes"
> str_extract(x, "\\S+$")
[1] "bob"    "Heaton" "Slaney" "Hughes"
```

Comment: Thanks! This was worked great! It was much easier than what I was trying to do. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
^.*(?=\\b\\w+$)
```

You need to put it in `lookahead`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/64

```
gsub("^.*(?=\\b\\w+$)", "", data_agent$List.Name, perl = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in the code.  One is that we need to escape `\s` and `\w` (in the OP's original post) by using `\\s` and `\\w`.  The second is that we are using a capture group by placing the `\\w+` inside the parentheses (`(...)`).  In the replacement, we can use `\\1` instead of `''` and it should work.

```
 sub(".*\\s+(\\w+)$", "\\1", data_agent$Name)
 #[1] "bob"    "Heaton" "Slaney" "Hughes"
```

Or using `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_last(data_agent$Name, regex='\\w+')
#[1] "bob"    "Heaton" "Slaney" "Hughes"
```

#### data

```
 data_agent <- structure(list(Name = c("Suzanne Sar Abay bob", 
 "Lucy Heaton", 
 "Lynn Slaney", "Michael Hughes")), .Names = "Name", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```